# Is there a setting to make Windows file explorer use forward slashes? Or an alternative file explorer app?

Tags: windows, bash, windows-explorer

git bash doesn't like backslashes, but windows supports both backslashes and forward slashes. I would like to just use forward slashes everywhere, especially file explorer so I can just copy a file path from file explorer and paste it into git bash.

If there's no windows setting for this, is there an alternative file explorer-type app I can install to use instead of file explorer? Two features I'd love to have in a file explorer app are 1)forward slashes and 2)automatic github-style rendering of any README.md file, if the folder contains one.

Comment: While the question is about slashes (and SU doesn't like people putting a bunch of questions in one post), Microsoft PowerToys happens to have a module that enables Markdown previewing in Explorer's already-existing preview pane.

Comment: "is there an alternative file explorer-type app" would be off topic here as we don't allow product request questions. If you must have an app that does this then maybe ask at [softwarerecs.se] but you would need to clearly define your requirements and read their [question quality guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).